# Open encrypted lotus notes email saved as eml

Tags: lotus-notes

I have several encrypted Lotus Notes emails saved as eml but when I tried to open them, the email only shows "Portions of this MIME document are encrypted with a Notes certificate and cannot be read".

Is there any way I can open these encrypted emails?

Comment: Did you check the EML- file with a Text- Editor? Is there encrypted content in this EML- files, or only the "Portions of this..." - Text? Might be, that the encrypted content was lost when exporting... then there is no way to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need the original emails in their NSF file store, and you're going to need the Notes ID file for the email account that the email was sent to.

Either that, or you're going to need someone with the ability and facilities to break RSA encryption and you're going to have to hope that the emails were encrypted for one of the old "International" Notes keys that the US government required Lotus to support back in the days of export restriction on encryption. You're also going to need to read the raw encrypted data from the NSF, and while the Notes API doesn't usually cooperate with that, I believe that the backup APIs do.